# Retrieve resources associated to an AWS account

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-java-sdk

Does AWS Java SDK have an api that could help me to retrieve list of resources (vpc, dynamodb, volumes, ec2 etc...) for a given AWS account number?
I have gone through AWS Java SDK docs at a higher level but everything is related to one specific AWS client for a given resource. 
I would like to have an abstract AWS client so that it could provide me just couple attributes of associated AWS resources to an aws account.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All AWS API calls are related to **specific services**. For example, you can request a list of Amazon VPCs, a list of Amazon DynamoDB tables, a list of Amazon EBS volumes -- but **each would require a different API call**.

Another option would be to use [AWS Config](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/WhatIsConfig.html):

> **AWS Config** provides a detailed view of the configuration of AWS resources in your AWS account. This includes how the resources are related to one another and how they were configured in the past so that you can see how the configurations and relationships change over time.

AWS Config can deliver a **Configuration Snapshot** into an Amazon S3 bucket at regular intervals (eg daily). This snapshot ([example](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/example-s3-snapshot.html)) is a JSON file that contains information about VPCs, Amazon EC2 instances and related resources.

However, the configuration snapshot only contains information related to a **limited number of services**, such as EC2, VPC, Amazon Redshift, Amazon RDS and Amazon S3. (See [Supported AWS Resource Types](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/resource-config-reference.html))